# how to get the diagonal components of numpy 3-D array?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy, diagonal

I have an 3-D array like

```
a = np.array(
    [[[1, 2],
      [3, 4]],

     [[5, 6],
      [7, 8]]]
)
```

and I want to get the diagonal component from this array, I mean,

```
>> np.array([a[i,i,:] for i in range(min(a.shape[0], a.shape[1]))])
array([[1, 2],
       [7, 8]])
```

Is there any faster way to do the same as above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `np.diagonal` you can also use `np.einsum`:

```
>>> a = np.arange(1,9).reshape(2,2,2)
>>> d = np.einsum('iij->ij', a)
>>> d
array([[1, 2],
       [7, 8]])
```

Advantage: It returns a writable view, so can be used to directly manipulate the diagonal in the original array:

```
>>> d[0,0] = -3
>>> a
array([[[-3,  2],
        [ 3,  4]],

       [[ 5,  6],
        [ 7,  8]]])
```

Comment: Nice! So it won't create any copy of a, and won't waste memory, is it right?

Comment: @seekworser Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 3):

[`np.diagonal`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.diagonal.html) works for arrays with more than two dimensions, which you can specify the axis to look at with parameters `axis1` and `axis2`, for your case, the default (axis1=0, axis2=1) works:

```
np.diagonal(a, axis1=0, axis2=1).T
# array([[1, 2],
#        [7, 8]])
```

It also works for arrays that have different sizes on the two axis looked at:

```
a = np.array(
    [[[1, 2],
      [3, 4]],
​
     [[5, 6],
      [7, 8]],

     [[9, 10],
      [11, 12]]]
)
​
np.diagonal(a).T
#array([[1, 2],
#       [7, 8]])

a = np.array(
    [[[1, 2],
      [3, 4],
      [9, 10]],
​
     [[5, 6],
      [7, 8],
      [11, 12]]]
)
​
np.diagonal(a).T
#array([[1, 2],
#       [7, 8]])
```

---

Or you can use [advanced indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing):

Create the range index:

```
idx = np.arange(min(a.shape[:2]))

idx
# array([0, 1])
```

Index the first and second dimension using integer arrays, and the third dimension with slice:

```
a[idx, idx, :]
#array([[1, 2],
#       [7, 8]])
```